# spark schedulingMode

Tags: apache-spark, scheduling

I am building a Spark App, in which I submit several jobs (pyspark).
I am using threads to run them in parallel, and also I am setting:
conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")

Still, I see the jobs run serially in FIFO way.
Am I missing something?

EDIT:
After writing to the Spark Mailing List, I got a couple of things more:

- Spark's FairSchedulingAlgorithm is not round robin: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SchedulingAlgorithm.scala#L43
- There is no preemption, that means even using scheduler.mode 'FAIR' you cannot be sure each stage will be executed 'a bit'. The scheduling happens just when resources (core) are available.

I was totally missing this last point

Comment: [Apparently not](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application).

Comment: I read the documentation, but I can assure you that they are still running in FIFO way, without any round robin

Comment: What [master](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) url did you pass?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, spark doesn't support threading for all kinds of jobs. You can only submit a job in parallel if it is a **spark action**.

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads. **By “job”, in this section, we mean a Spark action (e.g. save, collect) and any tasks that need to run to evaluate that action.** Spark’s scheduler is fully thread-safe and supports this use case to enable applications that serve multiple requests (e.g. queries for multiple users).

please follow this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/job-scheduling.html)

Answer (score 0):

How many executors do you have?

If you have 1 executor then FIFO is same as FAIR.

I am saying so because by default standalone mode creates 2 executors and in "cluster" mode you job would take 1 for driver and 1 for executor.

So you need 4 executors to run 2 jobs in cluster mode.